# Writing my result as horizontal as String

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Can someone help me how I can rewrite this query to get following result.

```
 1   2   3   4   5
U.T A.H E.Z R.Z S.A
```

Sometimes it will return more or less than 5 results.

[image]

My query:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(a.Vorname, 1) + '.' + LEFT(a.Name, 1) AS Name 
FROM 
    ADR_Adressen a 
LEFT JOIN 
    ADR_GruppenLink gl ON gl.AdressNrADR = a.AdressNrADR 
WHERE 
    a.Z_Klasse = 'BA' AND gl.GruppeADR != 'KIND'
```

Comment: Try looking at some of the ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string). The 2nd one looks simple enough.

Comment: Why do you need the data as columns?  If you just want to transpose it for _display_ purposes that's a lot easier in the display layer (report, web page, form, etc) than in the data layer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no pretty way to do this, if the number of rows is variable.

Building heavily on the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745042/efficiently-convert-rows-to-columns-in-sql-server), you need to dynamically build the query before executing it.

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- Build a list of ids for each of the selected rows 
SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',[' + convert(varchar,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LEFT([vorname],1),LEFT([Name],1)  )  ) + ']'
    FROM #ADR_Adressen
    LEFT JOIN ADR_GruppenLink gl ON gl.AdressNrADR = a.AdressNrADR
    WHERE a.Z_Klasse = 'BA' AND gl.GruppeADR != 'KIND'
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
      ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')

-- Build a query using the list of IDs selected above.  These are pivotted into column names

set @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
             select 
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LEFT([vorname],1),LEFT([Name],1)  ) ID,
                LEFT(vorname,1) + ''.'' + LEFT(Name,1) Name
             from #ADR_Adressen a
             LEFT JOIN ADR_GruppenLink gl ON gl.AdressNrADR = a.AdressNrADR 
             WHERE a.Z_Klasse = 'BA' AND gl.GruppeADR != 'KIND'
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Name)
                for ID in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p 
            
            '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Updated: Given that no ID field is available I've updated this to incorporate the ROW_NUMBER suggestion from Alex below

[Query example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/508909/pivot-variable-rows-into-columns)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i still have one Problem. I dont have any ID in my table. How can i solve this? Is it possible to build some row_number function into this query? @Paul Ellery

Comment: Do you have anything that uniquely identifies each row?

Comment: Updated to use ROW_NUMBER()

Answer (score 1):

this could help you, using [ROW_NUMBER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX)


SELECT  @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',[' + convert(varchar,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LEFT(a.[Name],1)  )  )+ ']'  AS ID
 FROM [ADR_Adressen] a 

 FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1,1, '')


DECLARE  @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @query = N'SELECT ' + @cols + N' from 
             (
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY LEFT(a.Name,1)  )   AS ID,
             LEFT(vorname,1) + ''.'' + LEFT(Name,1) Name
                from ADR_Adressen a
                LEFT JOIN ADR_GruppenLink gl ON gl.AdressNrADR = a.AdressNrADR 
                WHERE a.Z_Klasse = 'BA' AND gl.GruppeADR != 'KIND'
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(Name)
                for ID in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p 

            '
exec sp_executesql @query;
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, what do you mean?